# Delphi fast large bitmap creation (without clearing)

Tags: delphi, optimization, bitmap

When using the TBitmap wrapper for a GDI bitmap from the unit Graphics I noticed it will always clear out the bitmap (using a PatBlt call) when setting up a bitmap with SetSize( w, h ). When I copy in the bits later on (see routine below) it seems ScanLine is the fastest possibility and not SetDIBits.

```
function ToBitmap: TBitmap;
var
    i, N, x: Integer;
    S, D:    PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create();
  Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Result.SetSize( width, height );
  S := Src;
  D := Result.ScanLine[ 0 ];
  x := Integer( Result.ScanLine[ 1 ] ) - Integer( D );
  N := width * sizeof( longword );
  for i := 0 to height - 1 do begin
    Move( S^, D^, N );
    Inc( S, N );
    Inc( D, x );
  end;
end;
```

The bitmaps I need to work with are quite large (150MB of RGB memory). With these iomages it takes 150ms to simply create an empty bitmap and a further 140ms to overwrite it's contents.

Is there a way of initializing a TBitmap with the correct size WITHOUT initializing the pixels itself and leaving the memory of the pixels uninitialized (eg dirty)? Or is there another way to do such a thing. I know we could work on the pixels in place but this still leaves the 150ms of unnessesary initializtion of the pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was posted many years ago, however it's still relevant as recent Delphi versions behave in the same inefficient manner.

I've created a basic yet functional TBitmap alternative which is very light and efficient.  It can be extended in various ways of course to add desired functionality, however it is working and useful as it is.  Tested with Delphi 10.4.

```
unit VideoBitmap;

interface
uses Windows, Vcl.Graphics, SysUtils;

type
  TVideoBitmap=class(TGraphic)
  private
    FWidth, FHeight: Integer;
    FDC: HDC;
    FBitmap: HBITMAP;
    FBits: Pointer;

    function GetScanLine(Row: Integer): Pointer;
  protected
    procedure Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect); override;
    function GetEmpty: Boolean; override;
    function GetWidth: Integer; override;
    function GetHeight: Integer; override;
  public
    constructor Create(x,y: Integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property ScanLine[Row: Integer]: Pointer read GetScanLine;
  end;

implementation

{ TVideoBitmap }

constructor TVideoBitmap.Create;
var
  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
begin
  FWidth := x;
  FHeight := y;

  FDC := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
  if FDC = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
  with BitmapInfo.bmiHeader do
  begin
    biSize := sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    biWidth := x;
    biHeight := y;
    biPlanes := 1;
    biBitCount := 32;
    biCompression := BI_RGB;
  end;

  FBitmap := CreateDIBSection(0, BitmapInfo, 0, FBits, 0, 0);

  if FBitmap = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  if FBits = nil then raise Exception.Create('Error getting bits of DIB section');

  SelectObject(FDC, FBitmap);
end;

destructor TVideoBitmap.Destroy;
begin
  if FBitmap <> 0 then
    Win32Check(DeleteObject(FBitmap));

  if FDC <> 0 then
    Win32Check(DeleteDC(FDC));;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TVideoBitmap.Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect);
var
  CanvasDC: HDC;
begin
  CanvasDC := ACanvas.Handle;

  SetStretchBltMode(CanvasDC, STRETCH_DELETESCANS);
  SetBrushOrgEx(CanvasDC, 0, 0, nil);
  StretchBlt(CanvasDC, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right - Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top,
          FDC, 0, 0, FWidth,
          FHeight, ACanvas.CopyMode);
end;

function TVideoBitmap.GetEmpty: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

function TVideoBitmap.GetHeight: Integer;
begin
  Result := FHeight;
end;

function TVideoBitmap.GetScanLine(Row: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  Assert(Row >= 0);
  Assert(Row < FHeight);

  Result := Pointer(IntPtr(FBits) + (FHeight-1-Row)*FWidth*4);
end;

function TVideoBitmap.GetWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := FWidth;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

There's not many things you can do here - working with huge bitmaps is slow... but you can try following:

1. Set PixelFormat after calling SetSize() - this won't avoid initialization of pixels but might make it faster.
2. The fastest way I can think of is to use Win32 API functions ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491%28VS.85%29.aspx)) to create a DIB, and the assign HBITMAP handle of that DIB to a Handle of your TBitmap object.
3. Use memory-mapped files (once again requires calling API or alternatively there are some third-party libraries that can do that for you).

Comment: Thank you Alex, at the moment I try to use the memory blob and not a real bitmap at all. The moment however that I need to display the bitmap on screen, I need a bitmap (and incur the time penalty). 1 is substantially slower. 2 takes some time tweaking but until now does not give me the correct results. 3. is impossible because the images are not from file but solely in memory.

Comment: In this case you can try creating new bitmap using CreateBitmapIndirect API function ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183486%28VS.85%29.aspx ). I think it will use your existing data in memory and won't reallocate them.

Comment: When using CreateBitmap or CreateBitmapIndirect I shave off some 40ms (from 150+140 to 250ms)!

Comment: 40ms is probably what the call to PatBlt() took.

Comment: @Alex: noppes; patblt took 150ms, copying data took 140ms, calling createbitmap took 250ms (it copies the data on the background because it keeps working when you free the working memory). So it is slower but because you avoid one inefficiency it is faster and the best option so far.

Comment: Accepted: cannot find anything that is a faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did on a similar problem:

1. Copy the contents of *Graphics.pas* unit to a new unit called *MyGraphics.pas*
2. In the new *MyGraphics.pas* look for the implementation of the function *CopyBitmap* and comment out the line with: *PatBlt(NewImageDC, 0, 0, bmWidth, bmHeight, WHITENESS);*
3. Replace the uses of *Graphics* to *MyGraphics* everywhere in your Delphi project.

That's it, create faster empty Bitmaps...